# Print number as number in string type

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code :

```
string a =  "wwwwaaadexxxxxx";
```

Intended Output : "w4a3d1e1x6";

somewhere in my code I have `int count = 1; ... count++;`

Also, somewhere in my code I have to print this count as `a[i]` but as a number only .. like 1,2,3 and not the character equivalent of 1,2,3.

I am trying the following : `printf("%c%d",a[i],count);`

i also read something like :

```
stringstream ss;
ss << 100
```

What is the correct way to do so in CPP?

EDIT :

so i Modified the code to add a number at index i in a string as :

```
        stringstream newSS;
        newSS <<  count;

            char t = newSS.str().at(0);

            a[i]  = t;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Given your example of `string a`, can you show the actual output you want to produce, rather than a vague verbal description of it?

Comment: sure!.. Editing the post

Comment: i am counting the number of characters and then adding that to the string. i was earlier using a char a[].. but people here suggested to use string type instead for c++;

Comment: `printf("%c%d",a[i],count);` is fine. show complete code.

Comment: what do you mean by correct way?

Comment: So what's wrong with `printf("%c%d",a[i],count);` ? It looks like it should do what you want (assuming `i` and `count` are calculated correctly, of course). What again is the nature of the difficulty?

Comment: i did not want to use printf and that syntax as i am not very sure that it is strcitly c++. Also, using this is causing an incorrect  output.

Comment: isnt it more C like?

Comment: I would say C++ is compatible with most of C

Comment: @XiaotianPei printf("%c%d",a[i],count); doesnt work for me as it prints both a[i] and the count. I want count at the ith position in a,

Comment: @BhumiSinghal Why do you need to insert count in a? you can simply output the whole result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a stringstream to concatenate the string and the count,

```
stringstream newSS;
newSS << a[i] << count;
```

and then finally convert it to string and then print it or return (if this is done inside a function)

```
string output = newSS.str();
cout << output << endl;
```

But if your objective is only to print the output, then using the `printf` is fine.

If you need to update in place, then you can use two pointers. Let them be i,j.
You use j to set the new value and i to count the count. This is the standard runLength Encoding Problem.

Comment: the final objective is to print the final result as one string. I will hold the total result in a temp string and then cout it.

Comment: can u please explain what is happening here ?

Comment: If i need to do the update inplace then? Suppose i want a[i] = count and then resuse this "a" further?

Answer (score -1):

There is no "correct" way. You could use snprintf, stringstream, etc. Or you could roll your algorithm. Assuming this is a base 10 number, you want the number in base 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1194;
    int rem = 0;
    std::string output;

    do {
        rem = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
        output.append(1, rem + '0');
    } while(a != 0);

    std::reverse(output.begin(), output.end());
    std::cout << output << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is probably not what the OP asked for.